# Why my page is not centered?

Tags: html, css

I know that it's a newbie question, but if you could give me a hand and tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd really appreciate that:

While I was experimenting with HTML and CSS I decided to create a page with a fixed size that should be centered on the screen. To do so I decided to place the [body] tag by making its position relative and move it by writing:

```
position: absolute;
padding: 1em;
width: 960px;
height: 600px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-left: -480px;
margin-top: -300px;
```

Hovever it didn't worked quite as expected, and this is the result I'm getting:

[image: Screenshot taken from the page]

I was expecting to see the yellow box perfectly centered both horizontally and vertically, but instead I see that it's slightly off-center.
I tried to load the page on Safari, Firefox and Chrome and I'm getting the same results so as I already suspected I know that it's my fault :-)

Could you help me by explaining what I did wrong ?
Thank you very much

This is the complete HTML+CSS code of the page I have written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test 1</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        html {
            background-color: red;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        body {
            padding: 1em;
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 960px;
            height: 600px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            margin-left: -480px;
            margin-top: -300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    This is my website
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of the padding.

If you set the padding of the body to 0, it works (tested).

If you need a padding, add an internal 100% width div inside your body and give this internal div a padding.

Comment: You can try using the css3 box-sizing model instead of the css2 box-model. [Here is a good article on it](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/). That would solve the padding issue you brought up.

Comment: Thank you very much. Using your tip and the article that @imakeitpretty posted I started to understand that the inner padding concurs to the total width and height of an object; before I was thinking that, for example, if a div with a width of 100px had a left and right padding of 10px, the total width wouldn't change, but it seems that I was in error: the total width grows up to 120px in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test 1</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    This is my website
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
body {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 960px;
    height: 600px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: -300px;
}
```

**JsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/qecwx/

Answer (score 2):

The `margin-left` and `margin-top` should have -ve half values for `width` and `height` respectively:

```
margin-left: /* minus half of width */
margin-top: /* minus half of height */
```

You need to put in appropriate values.

In the container, you can also center using:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

provided you have already specified `width` too

Comment: If you look at his CSS, you'll see that he has already done that. The problem here is the padding.

Answer (score 2):

Just messing around with it for a few minutes and this is what I came up with that seems to fit your needs:

```
body {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 960px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

All I did was remove the margin-left: and did a margin: 0 auto; to align the left and right sides. I then set the margin-top: 10%; to get the top and bottom centered. Also I set the positioning to relative. Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to have the margins on your body tag set to **auto** like this

```
    body {
        padding: 1em;
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 960px;
        height: 600px;


        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

to center the body vertically takes a lot more work.